# Why is Dask to_csv saving files in parts?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

### Preamble for context:

I have a sample csv file that has more columns than rows (~300 vs 190), I'm trying to learn how it all works before working with the whole 80 million records.
I'm working on a google colab notebook.

### What I'm trying to do:

Read a CSV file, execute a value_counts() for all the columns and save the results

Here's the code, I left it as is :

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

# Here we're reading the csv
dfd = dd.read_csv(
    'drive/MyDrive/csvs/sample.csv', 
    delimiter=';',

    # Down below we specify the types of the first columns
    dtype = {'ID': object, 'BSID': 'UInt32', 'CAM': 'UInt32',
                  'AGZ': 'UInt32', 'Zen': 'UInt16', 'taw': 'UInt16'
                  },
    blocksize=64000000 # = 64 Mb chunks
)

# Here we convert the rest of the ~300 columns to UInt8

cols=[i for i in dfd.columns if i not in ['ID', 'BSID', 'CAM',
                  'AGZ', 'Zen', 'taw']]
for col in cols:
    dfd[col]=dfd[col].astype('UInt8')

# value_counts
for col in dfd.columns:
  result = dfd[col].value_counts()
  result.to_csv('drive/MyDrive/csvs/Value_counts-' + col + '.csv')
```

### What's going wrong:

When the code is executed, the results are stored as files named 0.part in folders that are named following the `Value_counts-' + col + '.csv` schema. I expect it to be saved as `Value_counts-' + col + '.csv` files in `csvs` folder.

Why is this happening?

***Additional question:***

Can I run value_counts() for all columns in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [doc](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_csv)

> single_file:bool, default False
>
> Whether to save everything into a single CSV file. Under the single
> file mode, each partition is appended at the end of the specified CSV
> file.

In your case you only have one partition (part.0) for each output - but Dask doesn't know that you don't need parallel writing from multiple chunks, so you need to help it.

Is there a better way? Well, it sounds like you have many more columns than partitions, so you could do `dfd.map_partitions(pd.DataFrame.value_counts)` and `sum` the pieces.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that, even though I have the docs tab pinned open.
I only have more columns than partitions only in this sample.